# Customising GCDWebserver's GCDWebServerFunctions file

Tags: ios, vpn, gcdwebserver

How can I customise `GCDWebServerFunctions's` `GCDWebServerGetPrimaryIPAddress` method without changing the file itself?

I want it to look for addresses using ppp0 interface if none can be found for en0 for devices using `VPN`. Can't seem to be able to subclass or extend using a category and I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`GCDWebServerGetPrimaryIPAddress()` is a C function, there's no way to "override" it.

You will need to fork GCDWebServer on GitHub and customize it to your needs.